# How to add Double in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

All I wanted to do is add variables which are both Double data type.
"$V{iAmt} + V{iFee}"

But error is "illegal use of null value or 'null' literal;".

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill your textfield with:

```
//if your variables are strings:
new Double(Double.parseDouble($V{iAmt}) + Double.parseDouble($V{iFee}))

//if your variables are already double
new Double($V{iAmt} + $V{iFee})

// checking nulls
new Double(($V{iAmt} != null ? $V{iAmt} : 0) + ($V{iFee} != null ? $V{iFee} : 0));
```

Comment: still error, "the method paseDouble(String) in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments Double" any other way?

Comment: @newbie123 try the second option :-)

Comment: tried the 2nd option, error again is " illegal use of null value or 'null' literal" huhuhu cannot believe adding Double in ireport can be this complex. :/

Comment: @newbie123 both iAmt and iFee are doubles?

Comment: yep both of them are Double, by the way im using ireport 3.0.0

Comment: @newbie123 one more attempt :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
  $V{iAmt}.doubleValue() + V{iFee}.doubleValue()
```